# VIF calculation difference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science-experience

I have found two method to calculate VIF but through both method my end result VIF value is very different. Why?

first method -
`X` is independent variables.

```
def comput_vif(considered_features):
    vif = pd.DataFrame()
    vif["Variable"] = X.columns
    vif["VIF"] = [variance_inflation_factor(X.values, i) for i in range(X.shape[1])]
    return vif

considered_features = list(X.columns)
compute_vif(considered_features ).sort_values('VIF', ascending=False)
```

Second method -
`considered_features` is independent variables.

```
def compute_vif(considered_features):
    X = df[considered_features]
    X['intercept'] = 1
    vif = pd.DataFrame()
    vif["Variable"] = X.columns
    vif["VIF"] = [variance_inflation_factor(X.values, i) for i in range(X.shape[1])]
    vif = vif[vif['Variable']!='intercept']
    return vif

considered_features = list(df.columns)
compute_vif(considered_features).sort_values('VIF', ascending=False)
```

Comment: Typo: `comput_vif`

Comment: I'm out of my depth, but the first function never uses `considered_features`.